# Converting user input (Integer) to conditional print statements

Tags: haskell, io, conditional-statements, getline

I am trying to get a numeric value from the user (ranging 1-10) and using conditional statements (`if number >= 1 && <=3`) print out health status (e.g. `putStrLn "your health is poor"`) but getting error message that I can't go past

```
health :: IO ()
health = do 
        putStrLn "State your health using numbers 1 - 10: "
        num <- getLine
        --putStrLn "Your health is: "
        if num >=1 && <=3
              then 
               do putStrLn "Your health is poor"
           else if num >=4 && getLine <=7
              then putStrLn "Your health is OK"
           else if num >=8 && getLine<=10
              then putStrLn "your health is fanstastic"
              else "Wrong health range indicated"
```

Error message:

```
healthCheck.hs:9:1: warning: [-Wtabs]
Tab character found here, and in five further locations.
Please use spaces instead.
|
9 |                         --putStrLn "Your health is: "   | ^^^^^^^^

healthCheck.hs:10:39: error: parse error on input ‘<=’
|
10 |                         if num >=1 && <=3    |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make some mistakes here, mainly with the types:

The line:

```
num <- getLine
```

means that `num` is a `String`, but you later use it as a number. You probably want to use [**`readLn :: Read a => IO a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn), and probably it is better to specify the type as well:

```
num <- readLn :: IO Int
```

In your first `if` cases:

```
if num >=1 && <=3
```

Is wrong since it is parsed as `(num >= 1) && (<= 3)`. The right operator is thus *not* a `Bool`, but an `(Num n, Ord n) => n -> Bool`, so a function. A function is not `True` or `False`.

You should replace it with:

```
if num >=1 && num <=3
```

Later you write:

```
if num >=4 && getLine <=7
```

but here again the types do not match: `getLine` has type `IO String`, so it is not a number, it is even not an `IO Int`. You probably want to reuse the `num`, so:

```
if num >=4 && num <=7
```

Finally in the `else` stament, you write:

```
else "Wrong health range indicated"
```

But the type of `health` is `IO ()`, not `String`, you thus should use `putStrLn`:

```
else putStrLn "Wrong health range indicated"
```

You can factor the `putStrLn` out, into:

```
health :: IO ()
health = do 
    putStrLn "State your health using numbers 1 - 10: "
    num <- readLn :: IO Int
    --putStrLn "Your health is: "
    putStrLn $
        if num <= 0 || num > 10 then "Wrong health range indicated"
        else if num <= 3 then "Your health is poor"
        else if num <= 7 then "Your health is OK"
        else "your health is fanstastic"
```

The above is still not ideal, since reading a string into an `Int` can go wrong. So it might help to use `readMaybe` here to make the program safer.

Answer (score 7):

One immediate problem is that you write:

```
if num >=1 && <=3
```

instead of

```
if num >=1 && num <= 3
```

But even then it will not work since the type of `num` is `String` (since you use `getLine :: IO String`, and you cannot compare it with numeric values.

You would need to use something like `read` to "read" the string into a numeric value (note that it'll crash if the string does not represent a numeric value).

Next, expressions like `getLine <= 7` will not work either, for the same reason: `getLine :: IO String`, so you cannot compare `IO String` with a numeric value.

This code will work:

```
health :: IO ()
health = do
            putStrLn "State your health using numbers 1 - 10: "
            str <- getLine
            let num = read str
            --putStrLn "Your health is: "
            if (num >=1 && num <=3 )
               then putStrLn "Your health is poor"
               else if num >=4 && num <=7
                  then putStrLn "Your health is OK"
               else if num >=8 && num <=10
                  then putStrLn "your health is fanstastic"
                  else putStrLn "Wrong health range indicated"
```

However I'd recommend you to look at `case` expressions or/and `MultiWayIf` as this may be a better way of writing this code:

```
health :: IO ()
health = do
  putStrLn "State your health using numbers 1 - 10: "
  str <- getLine
  case read str of
    num | num >= 1 && num <= 3 -> putStrLn "Your health is poor"
    num | num >= 4 && num <= 7 -> putStrLn "Your health is OK"
    num | num >= 8 && num <=10 -> putStrLn "your health is fanstastic"
    _ -> putStrLn "Wrong health range indicated"
```

Comment: Prefer `readLn` to `getLine`+`read`: it Does The Right Thing with exceptions when the input can't be parsed. In this particular case it doesn't matter, but it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the first warning, replace tabs with spaces.

To fix the error, add `num` to `<=3`

```
if num >=1 && num <=3
```

You will also need to add a `putStrLn` here:

```
else putStrLn "Wrong health range indicated"
```

Also, you can't use `getLine` as in `getLine <= 7`. 
Shouldn't that be `num` instead?
Do you really want to read another number from the user?